# Unable to get values of input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timesheet form that auto populates the hours worked based on the times input into the start and stop input boxes. I need to take all the values for the week and total them up and populate the weekly total box with that value. I need it to dynamically populate as the values populate in the daily totals box.

I'm able to get the `weeklyTotal` box to populate if I manually enter the values in the `dailyTotal` boxes but not if they are auto populated from selecting the start and stop times.

I've tried changing `change` to `blur`, `keyup`, `keydown`, etc with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $("#start1").val().split(':');
    stop = $("#stop1").val().split(':');

    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;

    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;

    if (hours < 0)
      hours = 24 + hours;

    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }

    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours1").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal1").val(hours);
  }
  $("#start1,#stop1").change(calculate);
 
});

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $(".start2").val().split(':');
    stop = $(".stop2").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;
    if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours2").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal2").val(hours);
  }
  $(".start2,.stop2").change(calculate);

});

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $(".start3").val().split(':');
    stop = $(".stop3").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;
    if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours3").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal3").val(hours);
  }
  $(".start3,.stop3").change(calculate);
   
});

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $(".start4").val().split(':');
    stop = $(".stop4").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;
    if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours4").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal4").val(hours);
  }
  $(".start4,.stop4").change(calculate);

});


$(document).on("change", ".txt", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".txt").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```css
.auto-style8 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #A5C4F1;
}

th {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* cellspacing */
}

td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* cellspacing */
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #CCFF99
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 57px; height: 22px;">START</th>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 52px; height: 22px;">STOP</th>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 87px; height: 22px;">Line Total</th>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 99px; height: 22px;">Daily Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="txt" id="start1" name="start1" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="stop1" name="stop1" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours1" id="" name="lineTotal1" readonly="readonly" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="dailyTotal1" name="dailyTotal1" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start2" id="" name="start2" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="stop2" id="" name="stop2" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours2" id="" name="lineTotal2" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="dailyTotal2" name="dailyTotal2" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start3" id="" name="start3" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="stop3" id="" name="stop3" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours3" id="" name="lineTotal3" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="dailyTotal3" name="dailyTotal3" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start4" id="" name="start4" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="stop4" id="" name="stop4" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours4" id="" name="lineTotal4" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="dailyTotal4" name="dailyTotal4" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Weekly total:</td>
    <td><input class="total" id="total" name="weeklyTotal" readonly="readonly" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should first try to resolve the console error in your code snippet.

Comment: Why are you defining the `calculate()` function so many times within multiple document.ready handlers...?

Comment: @Jason it's because you've left a `<script></script>` block in the JS section. I've removed it for you as it's not needed

Comment: So you duplicated the `calculate()` function for each table row... mmm.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I thought I had removed that but evidently missed it again. But that gives me a NaN value now instead of the sum of all the dailyTotals.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The first section of  jQuery was used from someone else and that is how I got it. It works so I haven't questioned it.

Comment: I've edited the code and removed the duplicated calculate() but the problem still exists. I get NaN in the final weeklyTotals box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this part:

```
$(document).on("change", ".txt", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".dailyTotalGeneric").each(function(i,e) {
    if(!isNaN($(e).val()) && $(e).val()){
        console.log($(e).val());
        sum += parseFloat($(e).val());
    }
  });
  $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

I made some changes, like add a class to all the inputs that sum weeklyTotal 
=> `dailyTotalGeneric` class.
And you have to check if the number you are trying to `sum` isNan or not exist to sum on variable.

```js
$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $("#start1").val().split(':');
    stop = $("#stop1").val().split(':');

    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;

    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;

    if (hours < 0)
      hours = 24 + hours;

    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }

    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours1").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal1").val(hours);
  }
  $("#start1,#stop1").change(calculate);
 
});

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $(".start2").val().split(':');
    stop = $(".stop2").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;
    if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours2").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal2").val(hours);
  }
  $(".start2,.stop2").change(calculate);

});

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $(".start3").val().split(':');
    stop = $(".stop3").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;
    if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours3").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal3").val(hours);
  }
  $(".start3,.stop3").change(calculate);
   
});

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
    var start = $(".start4").val().split(':');
    stop = $(".stop4").val().split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(start[0], 10) || 0;
    hours2 = parseInt(stop[0], 10) || 0;
    mins1 = parseInt(start[1], 10) || 0;
    mins2 = parseInt(stop[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = hours2 - hours1,
      mins = 0;
    if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if (mins2 >= mins1) {
      mins = mins2 - mins1;
    } else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
    hours += mins;
    hours = hours.toFixed(2);
    $(".Hours4").val(hours);
    $("#dailyTotal4").val(hours);
  }
  $(".start4,.stop4").change(calculate);

});


$(document).on("change", ".txt", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".dailyTotalGeneric").each(function(i,e) {
    if(!isNaN($(e).val()) && $(e).val()){
        //console.log($(e).val());
        sum += parseFloat($(e).val());
    }
  });
  $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```css
.auto-style8 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #A5C4F1;
}

th {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* cellspacing */
}

td {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  /* cellspacing */
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #CCFF99
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 57px; height: 22px;">START</th>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 52px; height: 22px;">STOP</th>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 87px; height: 22px;">Line Total</th>
    <th class="auto-style8" style="width: 99px; height: 22px;">Daily Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="txt" id="start1" name="start1" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="stop1" name="stop1" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours1" id="" name="lineTotal1" readonly="readonly" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt dailyTotalGeneric" id="dailyTotal1" name="dailyTotal1" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="txt start2" id="" name="start2" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt stop2" id="" name="stop2" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours2" id="" name="lineTotal2" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt dailyTotalGeneric" id="dailyTotal2" name="dailyTotal2" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="txt start3" id="" name="start3" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt stop3" id="" name="stop3" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours3" id="" name="lineTotal3" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt dailyTotalGeneric" id="dailyTotal3" name="dailyTotal3" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="txt start4" id="" name="start4" style="width: 69px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt stop4" id="" name="stop4" style="width: 66px" type="time" /></td>
    <td><input class="Hours4" id="" name="lineTotal4" style="width: 89px" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input class="txt dailyTotalGeneric" id="dailyTotal4" name="dailyTotal4" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Weekly total:</td>
    <td><input class="total" id="total" name="weeklyTotal" style="width: 96px" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Roy. I was just wondering if I needed parseFloat or parseInt somewhere in there but wasn't quite sure where to put it. Only problem is now that doesn't sum up all the dailyTotal boxes. It now only gives the total of the first box only. If I manually enter a value in the dailyTotal box it will sum it to the weekly total but it wont dynamically total the daily total boxes.

Comment: Solved, now sum the weeklyTotal

Comment: it doesn't work in a live environment. I copied that code you just edited to my server and it just displays a zero in the weekly total box.

Comment: The snippet is working, i can't guess what is the problem with your server. The original question is solved.

Comment: Ok I see the snippet is working now, before it was producing another box that blocked the Weekly Total. Thanks Roy you're awesome I can figure out why it's not working on my production environment.

Comment: Good, nice coding!

Comment: Found the issue on production server. Didn't realize you made a change to the class tag in the html. Made that adjustment and now it works perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178525/discussion-between-jason-and-roy).